# subclassing a class with a private constructor

Tags: java

implicit super constructor Example() is not visible for default constructor.Must define an explicit constructor. Is it so because I am defining a private constructor and then trying inherit the class in other class??

Comment: If the only constructor the class has is a no-arg constructor declared `private`, you cannot have a subclass.

Comment: Why do you guys down vote such question, if it's too easy to you it's not for other people.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is it so because I am defining a private constructor and then trying inherit the class in other class?

Yes. If your *only* constructors are private, then you can't create a subclass of that class, as there would be no accessible constructors to chain to - leaving nested classes aside (where accessibility changes a little).

Consider making your constructors protected, if you really want to be able to subclass the original class.

Comment: +1 You can have nested sub-classes. You have to decide whether you want constructors which can be used from another class e.g. protected, or you don't.

Comment: @PeterLawrey: IIRC in Java, nested subclasses wouldn't be able to access the private constructor of the enclosing class (unlike in C#), but you *could* potentially make an outer class subclass a nested class with a private constructor... if that's legal in other reasons. I didn't want to get into it here.

Comment: This compiles just fine in Java `public class A {
    private A() {
    }

    static class B extends A {
        private B() {
        }
    }

    static class C extends B {
        private C() {
        }
    }
}
`

Comment: @PeterLawrey: Interesting. I didn't think a nested class had access to the outer class's private members, but it's the sort of thing I only check when it goes wrong. Will edit the answer to make it correct without going into too much detail.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to subclass then you need to explicitly call super constructor from subclass constructor, and since it's private you can't call it! So make super class constructor at the least accessible level from subclass which is protected.